# Java code to Split Workbook into multiple workbooks based on a cell value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am looking for some help. I have an excel sheet A which has around 700 records. It has 5 columns where one of the column is Lifecycle. I want to split the file into two different files based on the Lifecycle cell value. For example if the cell value of Lifecycle column is X, put the record in A_X.xlsx file else put the records in A_Y.xlsx file.
I am using Apache POI.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can read from excel file using `Workbook`

Like this: `Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(EXCEL_FILE_PATH));`

Then you need to get your sheet like this: `Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(YOUR_SHEET_POSITION);`
But remember that sheets position starts from 0.

Then you can iterate over rows and cells using Iterator, for-each, and Java 8 foreEach with Lamba

Like this:

Using Iterator

```
       Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                // there you can check if cell.someValue == yourNeed to save on files that you need
                if(cell.yourValue == SOMETHING) {
                    saveOnExcelFile(YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH_ONE);
                } else {
                    saveOnExcelFile(YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH_TWO);
                }
            }
        }
```

Using for-each

```
    for (Row row: sheet) {
        for(Cell cell: row) {
            // there you can check if cell.someValue == yourNeed to save on files that you need
            if(cell.yourValue == SOMETHING) {
                saveOnExcelFile(YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH_ONE);
            } else {
                saveOnExcelFile(YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH_TWO);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using Java 8 forEach with lamdas

```
    sheet.forEach(row -> {
        row.forEach(cell -> {
            // there you can check if cell.someValue == yourNeed to save on files that you need
            if(cell.yourValue == SOMETHING) {
                saveOnExcelFile(YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH_ONE);
            } else {
                saveOnExcelFile(YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH_TWO);
            }
        });
    });
```

And in the end, don't forget to close the workbook using `workbook.close()`